# How to connect Celery worker to django test database

Tags: python, django, oracle, celery

I could like get my celery worker process to talk to the django test database.
Its an oracle database, so I believe the database/user is already created.

I am just trying to figure out what to pass the Celery/App configuration to get it to talk to the "TEST" database.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        .............
        'TEST': {
            'USER': WIT_TEST_DB_USER,
            'PASSWORD': WIT_TEST_DB_USER,
        }
    }
}
```

I have seen a stackoverflow article that talks about passing the settings.conf from the parent test setup() to the worker process. That may be necessary when the test database file is automatically generated in case of sqllite databases.

In my case, its a well defined oracle test database that I think is already part of the config/settings files.

so I am looking for a way to directly start the work process independent of the testrunner/testcase code.

Can some one suggest an approach to doing this?

Comment: Hope this is of any help..... http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#django-first-steps

Comment: This has the celery worker code talking to the 'default' database, not the test database. The test database gets created/connected when running the django test run, by the django testrunner code and gets destroyed at the end of the tests. I would like to start the worker in a test runner, after they are created and have it talk to the test database. I don't see it talk to the test database.

Answer (score 0):

You are regarding your test database as an ordinary database. So I think the best solution would be to define your test database as the default database under `DATABASES` settings in a separate settings file. And when running your worker you can pass the specific new settings file to your worker like this:

```sh
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='[python path to your celery specific settings file]'
# the command to run your celery worker
```